# TensorFlow & Keras AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I create a layer and call it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

dense = keras.layers.Dense(10)
X = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
dense(X)
```

Then I try to get its input shape:

```
dense.input_shape
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape.
```

Can somebody explain this error and how to fix it? It seems to me that the error as stated is simply wrong. I clearly *have* called the layer. And the layer has been built (for example, I see that `dense.weights` is not empty).

TensorFlow version 2.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting it in a sequential model (to get the `.predict()` method) and passing a numpy array:

```
dense = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
dense.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
X =np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],dtype=np.float32)
print(dense.predict(X))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. In fact, `dense(X)` works fine here too, no need for the explicit `predict` method -- the fix is just wrapping the layer in a model. Can you explain within the larger context of Keras why this is necessary and what the error message means?

Comment: Funnily enough, after updating my machine to tf 2.5, your code works on my machine... Is it possible you have something prior to this (some import, some definition) that interferes with this code?

Comment: Doesn't seem so, I just tried running a script with only tensorflow (and tensorflow.keras) imports and the code above. Still get the error.